# Linking to the latest post from home page in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails app where I have individual entries called films. I would like to display the latest entry's link on the homepage (separate controller) and I'm struggling to make it work.

My films_controller.rb is as follows (excerpt):

```
def show
   @film = Film.find(params[:id])
end
```

My home_controller.rb only has the following:

```
def index
end
```

And my view file (index.html.erb) has the following:

```
<%= link_to @film.last.filmTitle, film_path(@film) %>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find Film with 'id'=#<Film::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc93f2d1fd0>
```

With the `@film.find(params[:id])` highlighted.

Thanks!

Comment: From this line `Couldn't find Film with 'id'=#<Film::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc93f2d1fd0>` we can guess that the problem is coming from the query `Film.find(params[:id])`. You need provide more information from your database schema and models so we can help you. A plus: you need to check for `nil` values that come from the query in case the id passed don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The  `last` method:

> Find the last record (or last N records if a parameter is supplied). If no order is defined it will order by primary key.
>   [source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/last)

You can add a `@last_film` instance variable in your index controller and use it in the view.

```
def index
  @films = Film.all
  @last_film = Film.last
end
```

and in your index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to @last_film.filmTitle, film_path(@last_film) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `index` method need something, currently, it didn't connect with `ActiveRecord` like `model` or `table`, that's why

> ```
> Couldn't find Film with 'id'=#<Film::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc93f2d1fd0>
> ```

So if you need to show recent posts in the index then you could something like this

```
def index
   @films = Film.limit(10).order(created_at: :desc) #=> or you can use id
end
```

it will show last 10 records, for this in the `index.html.erb` like this

```
<% @films.each do |film| %>
    <%= link_to film.filmTitle, film_path(film) %>
<% end %>
```

In the other hand if you need to show only one post which is the last then you should modify this query like this like `limit(10)` to `limit(1)` or you can use use the `last` method like this

```
def index
   @film = Film.last
   #or
   #@films = Film.limit(1).order(created_at: :desc) #=> or you can use id
end
```

if you use this `@film = Film.last` then your index file will like this

```
<%= link_to @film.filmTitle, film_path(@film) %>
```

otherwise, you need to use `each` method which describes before.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you helped?